# connectionDidFinishLoading shows an errors in the NSString *jsonString line

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_buffer options:0  error:&amp;error] description];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (!error)
        {
            self.textField.text = jsonString;
        }
        else
        {
            self.textField.text = [error localizedDescription];
        }

        [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        [self.fetchButton setEnabled:YES];
        self.connection = nil;
        self.buffer     = nil;
    });

});
```

}

When i write this method then it shows errors in the fifth line. please help me I am new for the Iphone.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming the `&amp;` is not written like that in your actual code? What does the error say?

Comment: Then What should i do?.

Comment: You should tell me what the error says...

Comment: Expected ';' after expression and another error is Expected expression

Comment: Ok, in that case my original assumption was wrong. I'm guessing you copy/pasted the code from somewhere else? `&amp;` is a URL encoded ampersand, and aside from being gibberish amongst that line of code, the trailing semicolon is causing the code statement to end earlier than you intended. It should simply read `&error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `amp;`

from

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_buffer options:0  error:&amp;error] description];
```

It should be

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_buffer options:0  error:&error] description];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_buffer options:0 error:&error] description];
```